How should the SVG <use> element reference individual SVG elements in an external file
I have a collection of SVG icons in a single external file. In my React application I'd like to be able to render individual SVG elements within that file. My understanding is that I can utilise the use element as follows:
import React from "react";
import icons from "./icons.svg";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      >
        <use xlinkHref={`${icons}#calendar_today`} />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

The approach I'm taking at the moment renders some SVG space but not the calendar_today icon that resides within the referenced SVG code.
The following Codesandbox link demonstrates the issue
I'd be massively grateful if anyone could elaborate on how referencing external SVGs are supposed to be coded using the <use> element.
Thanks in advance

icons.svg is not a valid XML file because it contains multiple root elements.

Hi @RobertLongson thanks for your comment. That doesn't make any difference to the outcome (the svg has been through various iterations). I'll change the .svg file so it has a root / parent. However the outcome is that the SVG element is still not visible in the UI.

AFAIK most browser dropped support for <use> elements with data URL references for security reasons. See https://developer.chrome.com/blog/migrate-way-from-data-urls-in-svg-use. So you could reference the external file itself e.g <use xlinkHref={icons.svg#calendar_today} />

@herrstrietzel, thanks for your comment. You state, 'so you could reference the external file itself'. I am referencing the external file but nothing is visible as per the codesandbox link provided above.

If you inspect the svg in dev tools you see that react has inlines the complete svg as a data URL – which is not supported since ~2023 by most browsers
